# Error when using Matplotlib.image in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

Okay, so I just started [this](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) tutorial using Anaconda in PyCharm. I imported the correct libraries, but when I try to upload my image using this code:

```
img = mpimg.imread('FileName.png')
```

I get this error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../matplotlib/image.py", line 1323, in imread
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fd:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FileName.png'`

I tried putting in the file location like this:

```
img=mpimg.imread('FilePath/FileName.png')
```

But I got the same error. I want to follow the tutorial exactly so I'm not sure why this isn't working! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that there is that file in the folder... 
Try this command to list the files in that folder just to make sure that python atleast recognizes or reads the files.

```
import os
print (os.listdir('your path'))
```

Comment: No matter what I type in for the file path I get this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' '`

Does that mean Python isn't reading any of my files?

Comment: Try giving an absolute path. I mean give a leading slash which means an absolute path, or a path that starts at the root of your filesystem. No leading slash makes the path relative to your working directory.... I guess thats why it ain't working.

Comment: I guess, what it means is the image you are using is not a valid image file....Have you tried using any other image?

Answer (score 0):

you should give an absolute path for the image. for example 
   r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\stinkbug.png' adding r to remove the Unicode error

Answer (score 0):

I was providing the full path: "C:/user/username/Downloads/folder/file.ext"

When I changed it to relative, it worked for me: "Downloads/folder/file.ext"